# How can I install modulemesh package for Python PyBrain

Tags: python-3.x, pybrain

I want to install PyBrain to Python3.6(Windows 7).
In errors I encoutered file pybrain/structure/**init**.py
I fixed imports and set PYTHONPATH to load structures package.
Now it looks like this:

```
from connections import *
from modules import *
from networks.__init__ import *
from modulemesh import ModuleMesh
```

Now I get this error:

```
from modulemesh import ModuleMesh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulemesh'
```

I could not faind what the modulemesh package is in internet.
What is it and how can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I would prefer visiting [here](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/wiki/installation) or try reinstalling it.

also [here for complete setup filele](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/tree/master/pybrain)

Answer (score 1):

Hey [here](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/structure/modulemesh.py) is your required modulemesh